# RSS and Feedly: Feed not found

Tags: php, xml, rss, feedly

For some reason Feedly is unable to see my php generated RSS feed file. I'm starting to wonder if maybe my RSS file is not named correctly or isn't in the proper folder or if the file is bad itself. Here is my feed: https://hollowbit.net/rss.xml. As you can see I called the file rss.xml and it's in the root of my /var/www/html/ directory.

To add it to Feedly I tried going to this URL but it doesn't seem to recognize it: https://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/+http://hollowbit.net/rss.xml

I'm fairly confident that the RSS file itself is good since Firefox picks it up right away and loads the content correctly.

Any suggestions?

P.S. Not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question, if not let me know so I can switch.

Comment: http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhollowbit.net%2Frss.xml

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it off the unanswered list:

---

Feed was invalid, checked with http://feedvalidator.org/